# What does the comment say after the end of Esther?

Tags: megillat-esther

[image: MT note at the end of Esther]

I see that after the text, there is a short note at the end of each book, what do these notes say?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "סכום הפסוקים של ספר קסז וחציו ותען אסתר ותאמר וסדרים ה"

Translation: The total [number] of verses of [this] book [are] 167 and its mid-point (in verse count) [is the verse] "Esther replied and said" [[Esther 5:7](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Esther.5.7?vhe=Tanach_with_Ta%27amei_Hamikra&lang=bi)] and it has five [sedarim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seder_(Bible)).

Comment: Is there somewhere I can refer to that has translated them all?

Comment: For reference, the five sedarim start at: 1:1, 2:5, 3:8, 6:11 and 8:16

Comment: @Phillip are you talking about all notes at the end of every book?

Comment: the Schottenstein (Artscroll) chumash has an explanation for the notes after each parasha

Comment: @Phillip see rosends's comment.